# How to create a search bar to search keywords in my Tkinter table?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am making a UI. I have created a table with data from my csv, and would like to implement a search bar where you can type in a keyword and it will output the row with the keyword. TIA! Here is my code and [csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vFXGHjq9jrg3QUrEFVsuKsdtqu_DlY48/view)

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import csv

root = Tk()
root.title("Python - Import CSV File To Tkinter Table")
width = 900
height = 600
screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
x = (screen_width/2) - (width/2)
y = (screen_height/2) - (height/2)
root.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (width, height, x, y))
root.resizable(0, 0)


TableMargin = Frame(root, width=500)
TableMargin.pack(side=TOP)
scrollbarx = Scrollbar(TableMargin, orient=HORIZONTAL)
scrollbary = Scrollbar(TableMargin, orient=VERTICAL)
tree = ttk.Treeview(TableMargin, columns=("Link", "Name", "Email"), height=400, selectmode="extended", yscrollcommand=scrollbary.set, xscrollcommand=scrollbarx.set)
scrollbary.config(command=tree.yview)
scrollbary.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
scrollbarx.config(command=tree.xview)
scrollbarx.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
tree.heading('Link', text="Link", anchor=W)
tree.heading('Name', text="Name", anchor=W)
tree.heading('Email', text="Email", anchor=W)
tree.column('#0', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=0)
tree.column('#1', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=200)
tree.column('#2', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=200)
tree.column('#3', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=300)
tree.pack()

with open('output.csv') as f:
    # reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=',')
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        if len(row) == 0:
            continue
        link: str = row[0]
        name: str = row[1]
        email: str = row[2]
        # specialty: str = row[3]
        tree.insert("", 0, values=(link, name, email))
        

#============================INITIALIZATION==============================
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an Entry widget, along with a string variable that represents the Entry widget's contents, like this:

```
Searchbar = Entry(root)
Searchbar.pack()
SearchString = StringVar(Searchbar, "")
Searchbar.config(textvariable = SearchString)
```

2. Create a Label that you can use to display the relevant row with the keyword, like this:

```
SearchResultBar = Label(root)
SearchResultBar.pack()
```

2. Create a function that you can use to display the search result when the user enters the keyword.  You get the value of the keyword by calling SearchString.get()

```
def DisplaySearchResult(*args):
  Keyword = SearchString.get()
  {write some code to search your csv data and get a string to describe the search result, which we'll call SearchResult}
  SearchString.set(SearchResult)
```

4. Optionally, bind the function to the Searchbar so that the function runs when someone clicks enter or the searchbar loses focus, like this:

```
Searchbar.bind('<Return>', DisplaySearchResult, add = '+')
Searchbar.bind('<FocusOut>', DisplaySearchResult, add = '+')
```

That should do it.  Good luck!

Comment: `Keyword = SearchString.get` should be `Keyword = SearchString.get()`. Also please look at the naming conventions in python for variable names.

Comment: Good catch.  I have edited the prior response so that no one accidentally follows my erroneous code.  ;)

Comment: @TheLizzard I am getting this error: TypeError: DisplaySearchResult() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: DisplaySearchResult() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Comment: @GuitarMan look at the comment above - you need to add `event` in `def DisplaySearchResult():`